# Guide for http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite java wrapper library for SQlite?

Tags: java, sqlite, wrapper

I'm working on a large computer science school project using java and SQlite.

After finding out that the zentus.org wrapper errors on databases with ON DELETE and ON UPDATE clauses set, I have changed to the other wrapper found at http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite.

However, I find the documentation lacking somewhat when trying to get an overview on how it works and how to use it, and the function descriptions are very very short, and you have to scan through every function and somewhat guess how they work and what they do.  I wasn't able to find any guides on google on how to use it.

My question: Does anyone know a link for a guide or tutorial for the ch-werner.de/javasqlite wrapper, or else can give me a basic code example, or give a quick overview of querying the database and the most used functions, and how to use them?

Comment: Don't worry too much about your first question. We'll ask for clarifications or edit it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [JDBC Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)